# Confused about Stripe downgrades

Tags: stripe-payments

We are going to use Stripe to offer subscriptions with two support levels and two payment periods. Each one also has a free trail option and a quantity.

For example:

Telephone support
Max:OnDemand with telephone support and (yearly payment)
Max:OnDemand with telephone support and (quarterly payment)

Max:OnDemand with telephone support and free trial (yearly payment)
Max:OnDemand with telephone support and free trial (quarterly payment)

Portal Support
Max:OnDemand with forum/portal support (yearly payment)
Max:OnDemand with forum/portal support (quarterly payment)

Max:OnDemand with forum/portal support and free trial (yearly payment)
Max:OnDemand with forum/portal support and free trial quarterly payment)

Going from forum/portal support to telephone support is an upgrade and costs more so when we upgrade we prorate and invoice immediately which makes the subscriber pay for the upgrade straight away which is what we want. Also going from quarterly to annually is considered an upgrade and in this case it seems to cancel the quarterly contract and charges immediately for the new annual contract minus the amount left on the quarterly contract. This is also fine.

But when it comes to downgrading I am confused as to exactly what’s going on. Ideally we would like it to be that if they want to be downgrade then their plan will remain the same until the end of their subscription, After which they will be changed for their new plan. This seems to be what’s happening if they downgrade and keep the same payment period and we don’t prorate. Is that correct?

But when they downgrade and change from an annual payment interval to a quarterly what should happen in the case or prorate and not prorate?

What I think is does is when they downgrade and change from an annual payment interval to a quarterly and prorate the annual subscription is cancelled immediately and they get credited with the amount based on the remaining time left on the annual subscription minus the cost of the cost of the new quarterly contract. They will then be left with credit that used up each time the quarterly contract is renewed. Does this sound correct?

When they downgrade and change from an annual payment interval to a quarterly and we don’t prorate what happens?

Here is another example:

Max:OnDemand with telephone support and (yearly payment) costs £216 per year and OnDemand with forum/portal support (quarterly payment) costs £30 every 3 months.

A customer has 10 x OnDemand with telephone support (yearly payment) which is £2160

and they down grade to 8 x OnDemand with forum/portal support (quarterly payment)

What should the outcome be when they prorate and don’t prorate this down grade?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the answer I got back from Stripe themselves:

For the first question, yes; if your customer downgrades their plan to a plan with the same billing frequency (e.g monthly => monthly) and you don't prorate the difference, they'd just be charged the new amount on the next invoice when their current subscription period ends.

If you change billing cycle frequency (from an annual payment interval to a quarterly in your scenario), the customer would be charged immediately. This should occur regardless of your proration settings. Prorating should leave an account balance credit on the customer object which would be applied to future invoices, as you mentioned.

If the customer is downgraded from an annual payment interval to quarterly and you don't prorate, the customer would be immediately charged (due to the billing cycle change) for the amount of the quarterly plan and wouldn't receive any account credit.

There's a pretty comprehensive guide that covers subscription changes that should be useful here as well:
https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#upgrading-or-downgrading-plans

I hope this helps clarify things a bit! If you come across any other questions, please just let me know. I'd be happy to help.